# How to write shorter “without commission fee” max around 8 letter

Tags: abbreviations

I need to shorten `without commission fee` into 8 letter, any idea? I have no more space on the display to show this title.

Comment: `commission` is kind of important, other fees for other parties user have to pay

Comment: In OP's context, plain ***inclusive*** is often used to mean *inclusive of all additional charges (postage, commission, etc.)*. There's also ***net***, which is often somewhat broader (after taking account of all surcharges, discounts, taxes, etc.). The "opposites" to those (***exclusive, gross***) are often simply *implied* rather than explicitly stated, but they are used in many contexts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest **fee-free** or **no-fee**.